# Regex not strictly following negative lookahead?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex which is matching urls which don't have **quotes (double or single) at the end** and **have & (ampersand) in the url**.

The regex i made

```
([^'` "\n]+)\.([^ \n]+)&([^ "`'\n]+)(?!["'])
```

but it's just not taking the last word and matching the url

https://regex101.com/r/vpmqZH/1

[image]
Take the example of picture above

`google.com/cool?cool1=yes&cool2=no&cool3=no"`

the url should not match as it have " in the end

but it's just not matching 'o'
and matching the remaining url.

All I wanted to do is if this double quote is present in the end then just don't match the whole url.

Comment: Could you share us the regex101.com link with your example? Or past the text in plain instead of an image? This would help us find the solution.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vpmqZH/1 this is the url

Comment: Try matching what you do not need and match and *capture* what you need, see ``[^'`"\s]+\.\S+&[^"`'\s]+["']|([^'`"\s]+)\.(\S+)&([^"`'\s]+)`` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpmqZH/3). Where no substring is captured, omit those matches.

Comment: What programming language are you using? We need to code a real example. There are subtle differences between regex in different languages and different tools avaliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the lookahead active on the whole part after the ampersand.   We then have the option of

- `$` end of the line
  *or*
- `(?=\s)` positive lookahead for a space.

```
([^' "\n]+)\.([^ \n]+)&((?!["'])[^ "'\n])+($|(?=\s)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/6ZGpSX/1

Comment: but this won't match https://regex101.com/r/nCEXVY/1 case

Comment: you are matching if there is nothing in the end other then \n. after url there can be a space then the other word. (i. e. "hi this is the url {{url}} hi this is url"

Comment: Then it will match a space also in this case `google.com/cool?cool1=yes&cool2=no&cool3=no momdata`
https://regex101.com/r/WmDQKy/1

Comment: What programming language are you using? We need to code a real example. There are subtle differences between regex in different languages and different tools avaliable.

Comment: Javascript, `([^'` "\n]+)\.([^ \n]+)&((?!["'])[^ "`'\n])+($|(?=\s)` added positive lookahead and it worked

Comment: Can you update your answer according to the best. Like if you explain a little bit. It will be easier for others to understand. btw Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

For a match only, you can omit the capture groups, and use a negated character class and you should omit the backtick `` ` `` from the negated character class if you want to allow to match it.

```
[^'"\s.]+\.[^\s'"&]+&[^\s"']+(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^'"\s.]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `"` `'` `.`
- `\.` Match a dot
- `[^\s'"&]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `"` `'` `&`
- `&` Match literally
- `[^\s"']+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `"` `'`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdCBrG/1).